# tcPDF. MultiCell height not auto extending

Tags: tcpdf

I am stuck....being trying to solve this all day with no joy. I am displaying a table with 6 columns ( using foreach ()). Column 3 can have more than one line of text so i am attempting to use the MultiCell option with the other columns using cell option.

THe multicell is not auto extending to show all the text and is overlapping all the text on one line. I have tried all the different parameters on the function without success. I am sure there is something simple i have forgotten.

```
public function ColoredTable($header,$data) {
    // Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
    //$this->SetLineWidth(0);
    $this->SetFont('', 'B');
    // Header
    $w = array(40, 15, 150, 20, 20, 20 );
    $num_headers = count($header);
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) 
{
if ($i==0)
{$this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'L', 1);}
else if ($i==1)
{$this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);}
else if ($i==2)
{$this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'L', 1);}
else  
{$this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'R', 1);}
    }
    $this->Ln();
    // Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    // Data
    $fill = 0;
$h = 5 ;

    foreach($data as $row) {        
        $this->Cell($w[0], $h, $row[0], 'L', 0, 'L', $fill, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'T');
        $this->Cell($w[1], 0, $row[1], '', 0, 'C', $fill, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'T');
  $this->MultiCell($w[2], 0, $row[2], $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false, 0, $x='', $y='', $reseth=false, $stretch=0, $ishtml=false, $autopadding=false, $maxh=0 , 'T', $fitcell=false);
        $this->Cell($w[3], $h, number_format($row[3]), 'L', 0, 'R', $fill, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'T');
  $this->Cell($w[4], $h, number_format($row[4]), 'L', 0, 'R', $fill, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'T');
        $this->Cell($w[5], $h, number_format($row[5]), 'LR', 0, 'R', $fill, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'T');
        $this->Ln();
        $fill=!$fill;
    }
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
}
```

Comment: Why `multicell` set height with `0`?

Comment: Zero is what was there when i pasted the code. It does not matter what height i put. I have now set the height to 5 and the text still overlaps instead of extending the cell down.